# inverting colors in just one monitor (dual monitor setup)

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, xrandr

Using a dual monitor setup on Ubuntu 18.04, how can I invert colors on just one screen? I have been using [xrandr-invert-colors](https://github.com/zoltanp/xrandr-invert-colors) and when I run it all monitors get their colors inverted.

My xorg.conf:

`Section "ServerFlags"
        Option "DontVTSwitch" "on"
EndSection`

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod"  "sna" 
EndSection

Edit: xcalib -i -a also inverts the colors on both monitors.